# Too few template arguments error while trying to pass a list of pointers as a parameter?

Tags: c++, list, class, pointers, vector

I've made this "Socialite" class, and a separate "Faction" class. One of the arguments for the Socialite object is a vector of pointers to "Factions". I had used the Socialite class earlier without the 'factionlist' as a parameter, and it worked fine.

```
class Socialite
{
public:

 Socialite();
 Socialite(string lastName, string firstName, string userId, string picture, string website, string description, list<Faction*> factionlist);

 //other methods

 void newSocialite(string lastName, string firstName, string userId, string picture, string website, string description, list<Faction*> factionlist);
 void deleteSocialite(string lastName, string firstName, string userId, string picture, string website, string description, list<Faction*> factionlist);

 //other methods

private:

 string lastName_;
 string firstName_;
 string userId_;
 string picture_;
 string website_;
 string description_;

 vector<Socialite *> socialiteptr_;
 list<Faction*> factionlist_;



};
```

When I included it however, I get the errors:

```
 error C2976: 'std::list' : too few template arguments
```

and

```
 error C2065: 'Faction' : undeclared identifier
```

on the same line every time my method/constructor contains a factionlist. The solutions I looked up involved code using templates, and I'm not using any, so I don't understand what's wrong.

Extra info: My vector of pointers is stored in such a way:

```
 vector<Faction *> factionptr_;
```

And I make it into a list in such a way:

```
 list<Faction*> list_factions(factionptr_.begin(), factionptr_.end());
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "'Faction' : undeclared identifier" is your problem. The compiler does not know what `Faction` is. Most likely the problem will be fixed if you forward declare `class Faction;` before your other class declaration.

Answer (score 0):

As @Wojtek Surowka said, you can forward declare `class Faction`:

```
class Faction;

class Socialite
{
...
}
```

Or you can include header file with `Faction` declaration (if `Faction` declared in `Fraction.h` file):

```
#include "Faction.h"

class Socialite
{
...
}
```

But in this case `Faction.h` shouldn't include header with  `Socialite` class.